# How to run script from Jest test?

Tags: node.js, shell, jestjs

how do I run a shell script from a test (jest)? I tried this:

```js
var cp = require("child_process");

test("script", async () => {
  const script = cp.exec("./scripts/foo.sh");
  script.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log("stdout: " + data);
  });
  script.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.error("stderr: " + data);
  });
});
```

where foo.sh:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "fooooo"
```

and that gives:

> Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
>
> Attempted to log "stdout: fooooo"

Also, if I remove that it still doesn't show the console.log outputs

Any ideas?

Edit:
The "real" script is more complex:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "start script"
sandbox reset release -v
```

To make the `sandbox` command available, see:
https://github.com/algorand/sandbox#getting-started

For now, I managed to get it working by setting a timeout safely over the time that the script takes to complete, and call `done()` when the expected last log is shown:

```js
test("script", (done) => {
  //   const script = cp.exec("./scripts/foo.sh");
  const script = cp.exec("./scripts/sandbox_dev_reset.sh");
  script.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log("stdout: " + data);
    // this is a string that appears in the last log message
    // don't know how to make the test stop (successfully) otherwise
    if (
      data.includes(
        `Soon after sending the transaction it will appear in indexer`
      )
    ) {
      console.log("found the string! - done");
      done();
    }
  });
  script.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.error("stderr: " + data);
  });
}, 100000);
```

P.S. If it's of any help, originally this comes from a Rust test, where the script finishes normally (program continues executing without hacks):

```rust
pub fn reset_network(net: &Network) -> Result<()> {
    let mut cmd = Command::new("sh");

    cmd
        .current_dir(format!("/foo/bar/scripts"))
        .arg("./sandbox_dev_reset.sh"),

    let reset_res = cmd
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?
        .stdout
        .expect("Couldn't reset network");

    log::debug!("Script cmd stdout: {:?}", reset_res);

    for line in BufReader::new(reset_res)
        .lines()
        .filter_map(|line| line.ok())
    {
        log::debug!("{}", line);
    }

    log::debug!("Script finished");

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Testing Asynchronous Code](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous):

> It's common in JavaScript for code to run asynchronously. When you have code that runs asynchronously, Jest needs to know when the code it is testing has completed, before it can move on to another test. Jest has several ways to handle this.

You can use [callbacks](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks). When the script within that spawned shell is executed, call `done()` to notify jest the test case is done. **It is used for testing the callbacks, otherwise, the test case will not wait for the callback complete.** This means the test case is executed, but your callback is not executed. It's different with the `timeout` milliseconds option of the `test()` function.

```js
const cp = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

test('script', (done) => {
  const script = cp.exec(path.resolve(__dirname, './foo.sh'));
  script.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    done();
  });
  script.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error('stderr: ' + data);
    done();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74025882/index.test.js
  ✓ script (31 ms)

  console.log
    stdout: fooooo

      at Socket.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/74025882/index.test.js:7:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.175 s, estimated 10 s
```

**update:**

The default timeout of a test is `5000` milliseconds. If your script execution time is greater than this value, Jest will throw out a timeout error. This is its way of working. The timeout mechanism will abort those test cases that have been performed for too long.

You use the `timeout` option for `test()` function is right approach. See example:

```js
const cp = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

describe('74025882', () => {
  test('script', (done) => {
    const script = cp.exec(path.resolve(__dirname, './foo.sh'));
    script.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
      done();
    });
    script.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error('stderr: ' + data);
      done();
    });
  }, 10 * 1_000);
});
```

`foo.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 6
echo "fooooo"
```

I use `sleep 6` to simulate the execution time of your Rust script.

Comment: Thanks! that works for the simplified script I posted, but the real one (which calls another script which calls docker and so on) is showing the same error: `Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?` How to get around that? I'm porting a rust test (which spaws a child process and reads all the output lines with a buffered reader).

Comment: @User Please edit your question with a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: See edits. The script is third party and quite complicated, so I can't simplify it, but installing it is not difficult.

Comment: @User If your script execution time is greater than the default timeout milliseconds of the `test()` function, you should set proper timeout milliseconds for the test case.

Comment: Yes that's what I did, but the question is rather how to terminate the test successfully - currently (see edits) I've to check for a message, which is fine, as I can echo a termination message myself from the script, but feels a bit like a hack.. the rust script call doesn't need this.. anyway, I'll approve this answer as it solves the original question.